# Html.DropdownlistFor storing additional properties

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to build a custom filter. I am populating the filter fields in a dropdown list using Html.DropDownlistFor. This is my class structure. The FieldName will be my the field i am filtering, DisplayName will be the display name and FieldType will be the type of the field

```
public class SearchFilter
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string FieldType { get; set; }
}
```

Typically it can have values like

```
{ID, 'Employee Id', int}
{Name 'EmployeeName', string}
{DOB, 'Date of 'Birth' datetime}
```

The Html.DropDownlistFor takes only display text and value. I want to store the field type also, which I want to pass from the view to the controller. How can I implement that.

Comment: You can't. At the end, you just have a standard HTML select element, and by spec it will only every post the `value` attribute of the selected option element.

Comment: How do i add something like data-type: int in the generated html. I can process the value in the jquery

Comment: Not to be belligerent, but you can't, at least not with `Html.DropDownListFor`. It doesn't give you any ability to control the actual generated option elements, just the main select element.  You could perhaps write a custom `HtmlHelper` extension for this purpose, or you could forgo using `DropDownListFor` and manually create the select and option elements on page by iterating through your list of choices.